# How do I repeat only a part of a vector?

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector of: 0,24,12,12,12,96,12,12,12,12,12,12. 
I want to repeat only a part of it from 96 to the last element (12). The first part (0, 24, 12, 12, 12) I want to keep constant. 
Could you please help ?

Comment: `a[c(1:5, rep(6:12, n))]` where `a` is your vector and `n` is the number of times you want the pattern repeated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether number 96 is always located at the 6th position inside your vector. If so, please refer to the first comment underneath your question. If the position is variable, however, you could implement a simple query that identifies the position of 96 inside your vector, and then repeat the part of the vector starting from there as often as you wish (2 times in the below-mentioned code).

```
x <- c(0,24,12,12,12,96,12,12,12,12,12,12)

# Identify index of 96
id <- which(x == 96)

# Repeat part of vector starting from `id` 2 times
c(x[1:(id-1)], rep(x[id:length(x)], 2))

# # Which results in
# [1]  0 24 12 12 12 96 12 12 12 12 12 12 96 12 12 12 12 12 12
```